# Is MongoDB causing my Ubuntu 10.04 root file system to be completely full? If so how can I uninstall MongoDB?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-10.04, mongodb

A few days ago I decided to install MongoDB but, right after I installed it problems started happening. I outline exactly how I installed MongoDB and all the problems that ensued soon after at [this post at AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88258/i-cant-start-up-because-root-filesystem-is-full) I do want to mention that I talked to one of the people on the #mongodb IRC channel and they told me that MongoDB needs like 10GB to run.

[image: df -h output]

Could that be why my Ubuntu's root file system got full after MongoDB installation? Makes sense. If this is true and MongoDB is the issue, then **how should I go about uninstalling MongoDB?**

Also is there any way to keep MongoDB and save my Ubunutu 10.04? Or should I do a clean install of Ubuntu but give it more room thank just 10GB?

***UPDATE 1***

`cd / && du -hcs *`

8.4M  .... bin
34M   ..... boot
4.0K  ..... cdrom
625M  ... data
312K ...  dev
17M  ....  etc
45G  ....  home
0   ......... initrd.img
0    .........  initrd.img.old
275M ..  lib
13M ....   lib32
0   .........   lib64
16K .....   lost + found
3.9M ...  media
4.0K ....  mnt
442M ...  opt
0   ..........   proc
1.2M ....  root
7.3M ....  sbin
4.0K ....  selinux
204K ...  srv
0  ..........    sys
12K  ......  tmp
5.2G ....  usr
2.5G ....  var
0 ..........     vmlinuz
0 ..........     vmlinuz.old
54G ......   total

***UPDATE 2***

This is what happened when I tried to remove mongodb:

```
s3z@s3z-laptop:/$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-server mongodb-clients mongodb-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb is not installed, so not removed
E: Couldn't find package mongodb-server
```

This is strange because I can start up mongoDB's shell:

```
s3z@s3z-laptop:/$ mongo 
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: test
>
```

How come this is happening?

Comment: have a look at /etc/mongodb.conf, dbpath variable, and check that dir size (du -hcs /data/mongodb for example).

Comment: @milan Ok I looked in `/etc/mongodb.conf` and found `dbpath = /var/lib/mongodb`. `du -hcs /var/lib/mongodb` is `1.8G /var/lib/mongodb` and `1.8G total`. What does that mean?

Comment: Thats the size of all mongodb databases, so its not mongo that is filling up your disk.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could find out what is filling my disk up?

Comment: @milan ok I posted the results of `cd \ && du -hcs *` up in my post. What do you make of it?

Comment: @milan Yes I believe I am. I understand this now. I just deleted my /data/db dir and can now access Gnome Desktop. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably just run `apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-server mongodb-clients mongodb-dev mongodb-10gen` to remove *almost* all references to MongoDB and all its data. There will still be some references to MongoDB in the `/var/lib/` and `/var/log/` directories which can be deleted manually.

For *future* installs of MongoDB, you might want to put its home directory (and thereby its associated data) onto your `/home` partition, which still has plenty of free space. Heck, you could still *move* its data if you wanted. Up to you.

> Do you have any idea how I could find out what is filling my disk up?

The easiest way is the `du(1)` command, which will report the disk used for files and directories.

```
du -mx / | sort -n | less
```

The last lines will be the directories that have taken up the most space. The `-x` keeps it on one file system -- I presume you don't care so much about `/home` yet. The `-m` reports output in megabytes; if you want output in kilobytes instead, use `-k`. (I figure if you're tracking down ten gigabytes of content, you'll want to look for megabytes.)

Comment: Ok I ran the purge command as you suggested and got a weird result. I also took took out `deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen` from `/etc/apt/sources.list`. When I did `du -mx / | sort -n | less` bash just hung there for a really long time so I had to `CTRL+Z` out. Using `cd / && du -hcs *` worked fine and I showed the results in my edit **UPDATE 2**

Comment: I asked this question at mongoDB's Google Group http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/86a8f9c438c945cf# because I saw mongoDB was not fully uninstalled by @sarnold's instructions. I had to also add `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen` to fully remove it. Also keep in mind that even after that, not all dirs and files related to mongoDB get deleted. Running `locate mongodb` will prove this. I did this and saw files still in `/var/lib/` and `/var/log/`. You can delete those manually.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on how mongodb was installed.  If you didn't install it via apt but perhaps via another download then apt couldn't uninstall it.  However its rare that an installer would remove application created data as part of its uninstall process.

Just run the Disk Usage Analyser (on the Applications -> Accessories menu) on your / folder to see where the space is being taken up.  Then perhaps you can backup and remove the file(s) in question.